# Spring-Batch 5 need for explicit TransactionManagers in StepBuilder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-transactions

What TxManager are we supposed to inject here, one binded to the domain data datasource or one binded to the batch schema datasource?

I'm creating a SCDF Task with a Batch workflow. I had to define 2 datasources, 2 txManagers and the like:
a) 1 coming from SCDF server datasource with all batch and task tables
b) 1 defining my app domain database

So in this scenario, are we supposed to pass the first or the second txManager?
I read in the migration guide that this was previously implicit configured by BatchConfigurer so I guess it's (a), because we used to pass there the batch internals datasource, but the documentation I am reading seems to refer to user data transaction management and besides, there is already a configuration of a txManager for internal batch in BatchAutoconfiguration therefore it would not make much sense to reconfigure it again on every step no?

P.S: I think the documentation could be more specific https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/step/chunk-oriented-processing/configuring.html#page-title